# Django Admin Search Field CheckBox

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a standard way in Django Admin to add a checkbox next to the search to select (at runtime) on what field to search on?

I know there is the AdminModel attribute `search_fields = ['one_field', 'other_field']` etc. But for this project I am in need to select one field at the time.

Any idea welcome! Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

Django Admin doesn't provide custom checkbox for search fields but you can implement a similar functionality by overriding the django search. You can use prefix based searching.

**Code Sample**

```
class UserTimelineAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user_screen_name','user_name', 'created_at',)
    search_fields = ['user_screen_name','user_name']

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        new_queryset, use_distinct = super().get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)

        if search_term.startswith('screen_name-'):
            search_term = search_term.replace('screen_name-','')
            try:
                new_queryset |= queryset.filter(user_screen_name=search_term)
            except:
                pass

        elif search_term.startswith('user_name-'):
            search_term = search_term.replace('user_name-','')
            try:
                new_queryset |= queryset.filter(user_name=search_term)
            except:
                pass


        return new_queryset, use_distinct
```

1. To search on the first field i.e. user_screen_name, use the prefix **screen_name-** in the search input. Example: *screen_name-XYZ* will search on all users with screen_name XYZ.
2. To search on the second field i.e. user_name, use the prefix **user_name-** in the search input. Example: *user_name-XYZ* will search on all users with user_name XYZ.
3. To get the combined results on both the search fields don't use any prefix.

**Screenshot**

The following screenshot shows searching only with screen_name field (prefix used **screen_name-**)

[image: Searching with screen_name field]

**Edit**

- self.model.objects.filter replaced with queryset.filter
- Screenshot Added

This is done to avoid the errors on using list filters with search field filters.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

The default implementation searches the fields named in ModelAdmin.search_fields.

This method may be overridden with your own custom search method. For example, you might wish to search by an integer field, or use an external tool such as Solr or Haystack. You must establish if the queryset changes implemented by your search method may introduce duplicates into the results, and return True in the second element of the return value.

For example, to enable search by integer field, you could use:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'age')
    search_fields = ('name',)

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super(PersonAdmin, self).get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        try:
            search_term_as_int = int(search_term)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(age=search_term_as_int)
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/

Add the logic u need there